# Getting "dictionary update sequence element #0 error" while training linear regression model in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, linear-regression

So I am completely new to Machine learning using tensorflow.I was doing simple linear regression which has multiple input classes. Let me share code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

# Make numpy values easier to read.
np.set_printoptions(precision=3, suppress=True)

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers
college_data = pd.read_csv("Admission.csv",names=["GRE Score","TOEFL Score","University Rating","SOP","LOR","CGPA","Research","Chance of Admit"]) 

college_data = college_data.iloc[1: , :]

X = college_data.iloc[:,:-1].values
Y = college_data.iloc[:, -1].values

feature_columns = []
NUMERIC_COLUMNS = ["GRE Score","TOEFL Score","University Rating","SOP","LOR","CGPA","Research","Chance of Admit"]
for feature_name in NUMERIC_COLUMNS:
  feature_columns.append(tf.feature_column.numeric_column(feature_name, dtype=tf.float32))
  
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=0.2)

#this is the function which is throwing error later on when called during train method
def make_input_fn(data_df, label_df, num_epochs=10, shuffle=True, batch_size=32):
  def input_function():  
    ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(data_df), label_df))  
    if shuffle:
      ds = ds.shuffle(1000)  
    ds = ds.batch(batch_size).repeat(num_epochs)
    return ds  
  return input_function  # return a function object for use
  
train_input_fn = make_input_fn(x_train, y_train)  # here we will call the input_function that was returned to us to get a dataset object we can feed to the model
eval_input_fn = make_input_fn(x_test, y_test, num_epochs=1, shuffle=False)


linear_est = tf.estimator.LinearClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns)

#And now we get the error
linear_est.train(input_fn=train_input_fn,steps=100)
```

And this is the error

```
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 7; 2 is required
```

I kind of have some idea that my variable x_train has shape (400,7) 400 rows of 7 columns each. But this code was supposed to run for multiple column input.
One more feeling which I am getting is that the error has something to do with the line

```
 ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(data_df), label_df))
```

I have done variations like `dict(enumerate(data_tf.flatten(),1)`
and other fixes but to no use. I even tried lists but still I am getting some other weird error.
Let me share the jupyter notebook from where I was learning
[Link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/15Cyy2H7nT40sGR7TBN5wBvgTd57mVKay#forceEdit=true&sandboxMode=true&scrollTo=I3qcbvOYbIwa)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the error. Please find the working code below.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers
college_data = pd.read_csv("Admission.csv",names=["GRE Score","TOEFL Score","University Rating","SOP","LOR","CGPA","Research","Chance of Admit"]) 



college_data = college_data.iloc[1: , :]

college_data=college_data.astype({'GRE Score': int,
                    'TOEFL Score': int,
                    'University Rating': int,
                    'SOP': float,
                    'LOR': float,
                    'CGPA': float,
                    'Research': int,
                    'Chance of Admit': float})

X = college_data.iloc[:,:-1]
Y = college_data.iloc[:, -1]

feature_columns = []
NUMERIC_COLUMNS = ["GRE Score","TOEFL Score","University Rating","SOP","LOR","CGPA","Research"]
for feature_name in NUMERIC_COLUMNS:
  feature_columns.append(tf.feature_column.numeric_column(feature_name, dtype=tf.float32))
  
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=0.2)

def train_input_fn(num_epochs=10, shuffle= True, batch_size=32):
  ds=tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(x_train),y_train ))
  if shuffle:
      ds = ds.shuffle(100)  
  ds = ds.batch(batch_size).repeat(num_epochs)
  return ds 

def eval_input_fn(num_epochs=1, shuffle= False, batch_size=32):
  ds=tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(x_test),y_test ))
  if shuffle:
      ds = ds.shuffle(100)  
  ds = ds.batch(batch_size).repeat(num_epochs)
  return ds 

linear_est = tf.estimator.LinearClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns)
linear_est.train(input_fn=train_input_fn,steps=100)
```

Output is as follows:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Using default config.
WARNING:tensorflow:Using temporary folder as model directory: /tmp/tmpma8_kne8
INFO:tensorflow:Using config: {'_model_dir': '/tmp/tmpma8_kne8', '_tf_random_seed': None, '_save_summary_steps': 100, '_save_checkpoints_steps': None, '_save_checkpoints_secs': 600, '_session_config': allow_soft_placement: true
graph_options {
  rewrite_options {
    meta_optimizer_iterations: ONE
  }
}
, '_keep_checkpoint_max': 5, '_keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours': 10000, '_log_step_count_steps': 100, '_train_distribute': None, '_device_fn': None, '_protocol': None, '_eval_distribute': None, '_experimental_distribute': None, '_experimental_max_worker_delay_secs': None, '_session_creation_timeout_secs': 7200, '_checkpoint_save_graph_def': True, '_service': None, '_cluster_spec': ClusterSpec({}), '_task_type': 'worker', '_task_id': 0, '_global_id_in_cluster': 0, '_master': '', '_evaluation_master': '', '_is_chief': True, '_num_ps_replicas': 0, '_num_worker_replicas': 1}
INFO:tensorflow:Calling model_fn.
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/canned/linear.py:1478: UserWarning: `layer.add_variable` is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Please use `layer.add_weight` method instead.
  getter=tf.compat.v1.get_variable)
INFO:tensorflow:Done calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Create CheckpointSaverHook.
INFO:tensorflow:Graph was finalized.
INFO:tensorflow:Running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Done running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Calling checkpoint listeners before saving checkpoint 0...
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 0 into /tmp/tmpma8_kne8/model.ckpt.
INFO:tensorflow:Calling checkpoint listeners after saving checkpoint 0...
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.6931472, step = 0
INFO:tensorflow:Calling checkpoint listeners before saving checkpoint 100...
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 100 into /tmp/tmpma8_kne8/model.ckpt.
INFO:tensorflow:Calling checkpoint listeners after saving checkpoint 100...
INFO:tensorflow:Loss for final step: 1.3445289.
<tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.canned.linear.LinearClassifierV2 at 0x7fd62518a610>
```

Let us know if the issue still persists. Thanks!